# ExtJS Ajax request failed with JSON Data

Tags: java, ajax, json, extjs

I am sending modified record using extjs ajax to java side rest service ,Here is code..

```
Ext.Ajax.request( {
                        url : saveUrl,
                        params: {unitMonthList: Ext.JSON.encode(jsonData)},
                        method : "POST",
                        isUpload : true,
                        timeout: 300000,
                        jsonData : jsonData,
                        success : function(resp, opts) {
                            var value = resp.responseText;
                            var result = JSON.parse(value);
                            Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                            if(result.success){
                                    var umCostStore = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Unitmonths');
                                    umCostStore.commitChanges();
                                    Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                                    Ext.Msg.show({
                                        title : 'Notification',
                                        msg : 'Data saved successfully!',
                                        buttons : 1,                                
                                        cls : 'msgBtnCls'
                                    });
                            }
                        },
                        failure : function(resp, opts) {
                            Ext.MessageBox.hide();
                            Ext.Msg.show({
                                title : 'Notification',
                                msg : 'Error occurred. Please try again later..',
                                buttons : 1,                                
                                cls : 'msgBtnCls'
                            });
                        }
                    });




@POST
@Path("saveUnitMonths")
@Produces("application/json")
public String saveUnitMonths(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context ServletContext servletContext) throws ParseException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String unitMonthList = request.getParameter("unitMonthList");

    }
```

above code working fine up to 5 records,but for more than 5 records ajax request failed giving me 500 error code and executing failure call back function.
It's not calling  server side at all.
Please help me to understand whats going wrong for more than 5 record.
if i removed Ext.JSON.encode(jsonData) and use jsonData directly then Ajax calling server side for more than 5 record also but i can't handle that non JSON data at server side.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please see and help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122306/call-java-class-from-extjs-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sending your data twice? In your request there is `jsonData` in

```
params: {unitMonthList: Ext.JSON.encode(jsonData)},
```

and once again in

```
jsonData : jsonData
```

Maybe try  removing one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by removing **Ext.JSON.encode(jsonData)** some how **Ext.JSON.encode(**) function failed to encode record more than 5 ,so i simply send **jsonData : jsonData** as array to server without encoding.