# Call java class from ExtJs ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, extjs

Using Extjs + Maven + Spring.

I am writing an Extjs code. I want to update my jason file. Therefore I have to use any server side programming. I want to use JAVA for that.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'HelloWorld',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        id: openwindows,
        state: space
    },                                                                              
    scope : this,
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here
        //alert(text);
        console.log(text);
    },
    failure: function ( response ) {
        var text = response.responseText;
        //alert(text);
        console.log(text);
    }
});
```

But it gets me an error

> ### HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /parent/HelloWorld.
>   Reason:
>
> ```
>     NOT_FOUND
> ```
>
> ---
>
> *Powered by
>   Jetty://*

I tried 100 things to get this work but I had no luck.

Do I have to follow such structure for the JAVA/Servlet side.

If anyone knew that please let me know.

Kind Regards,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make ajax call to spring services.Do something below.Pass the full URL of your backend service.Make sure that you are passing correct URL,header information and post parameters.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://ip_address:port/HelloWorld',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        id: openwindows,
        state: space
    },                                                                              
    scope : this,
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here
        //alert(text);
        console.log(text);
    },
    failure: function ( response ) {
        var text = response.responseText;
        //alert(text);
        console.log(text);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already tried it. I found one article here but I don't know where to write servlet. In same file or some where else. e.g. http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/06/how-to-post-and-get-json-between-extjs.html

Comment: I mean to say that where to write java class (in which folder). And how to do mapping for that?